# Disable clustering at max zoom level using android-maps-utils

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new here, so any feedback is welcome. I'm trying to use a DefaultClusterRenderer to show some custom clusters, and I'm trying to get it not to cluster when the map is fully zoomed in. So I found this answer to the exact same question:
[Disable clustering at max zoom level with Googles android-maps-utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909260/disable-clustering-at-max-zoom-level-with-googles-android-maps-utils)
so I tried that code, but I'm getting a ***Not on the main thread*** error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I have this in my constructor

```
public EspecieRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<T> clusterManager) {
    super(context, map, clusterManager);
    this.mMap = map;
...
}
```

and then I'm doing

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<T> cluster) {
    final float currentZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
    final float currentMaxZoom = mMap.getMaxZoomLevel();
    return currentZoom < currentMaxZoom && cluster.getSize() >= 10;
}
```

Here is how I'm initializing the cluster. I'm using threads because I have close to 200 species to load, each with one or more markers to add to the map

```
private void setUpClusterer() {
    clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, googleMap);
    clusterManager.setRenderer(new EspecieRenderer<>(this, googleMap, clusterManager));
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
    ArrayList<Especie> especies = (ArrayList<Especie>) Especie.list(this);
    for (Especie especie : especies) {
        ExecutorService queue = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        queue.execute(new EspecieLoader(this, especie));
    }
}
```

Where EspecieLoader

```
public class EspecieLoader implements Runnable {
    private MainActivity context;
    private Especie especie;

    public EspecieLoader(MainActivity mainActivity, Especie especie) {
        this.context = mainActivity;
        this.especie = especie;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<Foto> fotos = Foto.findAllByEspecieWithdCoords(context, especie);
        String nombre = especie.getNombreCientifico();
        for (Foto foto : fotos) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(foto.getLatitud(), foto.getLongitud());
            Bitmap bitmap;
            String path = "new/" + foto.getPath().replaceAll("-", "_").toLowerCase();
            try {
                bitmap = ResourcesHelper.getEncyclopediaAssetByName(context, path);
                EspecieMarker especieMarker = new EspecieMarker(nombre, bitmap, latLng);
                context.addSpeciesMarker(especieMarker);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this when I try to run my app:

```
07-16 19:18:41.402 31151-32075/com.lzm.Cajas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-47332
Process: com.lzm.Cajas, PID: 31151
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
    2at maps.f.g.b(Unknown Source)
    at maps.z.F.a(Unknown Source)
    at maps.af.t.a(Unknown Source)
    at vl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:51)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
    at com.lzm.Cajas.map.EspecieRenderer.shouldRenderAsCluster(EspecieRenderer.java:62)
    at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$RenderTask.run(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:416)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Could you show how are you initialising the cluster manager and adding items to it?

Comment: I have updated my question with the initialization of the cluster

Comment: The problem is that you must add the markers on the main thread, not on a `Runnable`

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I'm going to try and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**2022 UPDATE** - Since the previous answer is a bit messy and the google maps camera events have changed here's a more up-to-date and elegant solution:

Extend `ClusterManager` end expose a property that indicates whether the markers should be clustered according to the zoom level and update it in the `onCameraIdle` event.

```kotlin
open class ZoomClusterManager<T : ClusterItem>(
    context: Context,
    private val map: GoogleMap
) : ClusterManager<T>(context, map) {
    companion object {
        private const val CLUSTER_MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 9
    }

    private var _shouldClusterZoom: Boolean = true
    val shouldClusterZoom get() = _shouldClusterZoom

    override fun onCameraIdle() {
        super.onCameraIdle()
        _shouldClusterZoom = map.cameraPosition.zoom < CLUSTER_MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL
    }
}
```

Depending on the usecase you might want to have `CLUSTER_MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL` as property in the constructor for better reusability of the class.
Then extend `DefaultClusterRenderer` as well. In the constructor pass your extended version of ClusterManager, override `shouldRenderAsCluster` and check the previously exposed property like this:

```kotlin
open class ZoomClusterRenderer<T : ClusterItem>(
    context: Context,
    map: GoogleMap,
    private val clusterManager: ZoomClusterManager<T>
) : DefaultClusterRenderer<T>(context, map, clusterManager) {

    override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<T>): Boolean {
        return super.shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster) && clusterManager.shouldClusterZoom
    }
}
```

In the end wire everything up in your fragment where you're setting up the map:

```kotlin
val clusterManager = ZoomClusterManager<ClusterItem>(requireContext(), googleMap)
clusterManager.renderer = ZoomClusterRenderer(requireContext(), googleMap, clusterManager)
googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager)
```

---

**Old answer** - I've run into the same need just today. This is my solution:
Since you can't set setOnCameraChangeListener twice, remove

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
```

and replace it with

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            shouldCluster_zoom = cameraPosition.zoom < 9; //disables the cluster at 9 and higher zoom levels
            clusterManager.onCameraChange(cameraPosition); //Replaces googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(clusterManager);
        }
    });
```

"`shouldCluster_zoom`" obviously is a global variable, static and boolean.
Now in "`shouldRenderAsCluster`" method check, according to the zoom, if markers should be clustered:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<T> cluster) {
        return super.shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster) && Your_class_name.shouldCluster_zoom;
    }
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know

Comment: @luzma so ? it works or not ? give us a ur feedback please

Comment: the lib should add this option. should be real handy

Answer (score 1):

Editing on top of @Alberto97's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502197/2579739):

OnCameraChange method is now deprecated. They replaced GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() with three camera listeners :

- GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener - Callback interface for when the camera motion starts.
- GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener - Callback interface for when the camera changes position.
- GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener - Callback interface for when camera movement has ended.

I would use OnCameraIdleListener

```
  googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraIdle() {
                shouldCluster_zoom = cameraPosition.zoom < 9;
                clusterManager.onCameraIdle();
            }
        });
```